# LWC with a Dropdown below the textarea

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am creating a dropdown lwc that has to simulate the search feature in salesforce, everything works fine except by the fact that the dropdown goes below the textarea stacked below. I report an image to show you better

[image]

For the records the modal is an Aura in which there are an LWC for the lightning inputs and the textarea, in the LWC there is another LWC that contains only the dropdown component.

Is there a way to take the dropdown over the textarea? I have tried working with the z-index property but I was not able to move up the dropdown in respect with the textarea. Thanks in advance!

I report the code below (first is the LWC of the table and the second the one of the dropdown)

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isLoading}>
        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-around_x-large">
            <div class="slds-is-relative">
                <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={isInserting}>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={elements} for:item="row">
                    <tr key={row.tableId} data-id={row.tableId} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <template for:each={row.columns} for:item="column">
                            <td key={column.name} data-id={column.name} class="table-align-top">
                                <template if:true={column.isCurrent}>
                                    <lightning-input 
                                    toggle-id="toggle"
                                    name={column.name}
                                    value={column.value}
                                    label={column.label}
                                    disabled={column.disabled}
                                    onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
                                </template>
                                <template if:true={column.isToChange}>
                                    <div class="slds-modal__content_listbox">
                                        <c-lwc-lookup 
                                            input-label="Ricerca dealer"
                                            onselected={handleNewDealer}
                                            onremovesingleitem={handleDeleteDealer}
                                            lookup-placeholder="Ricerca dealer"
                                            object-name="Account"
                                            key-field-api-name="Name"
                                            additional-key-field-api-name="ExternalIdBaan__c"
                                            additional-field-api-name="ExternalIdBaan__c"
                                            additional-field="ExternalIdBaan__c"
                                            other-fields-to-retrieve="ExternalIdBaan__c"
                                            fixed-where-clause="Type = 'D' AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Dealer'"
                                            field-excluding="Id"
                                            value-excluding={currentDealerId}
                                            invalid-option-chosen-message="Nessun dealer scelto">
                                        </c-lwc-lookup>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            </td>
                        </template>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="slds-m-horizontal_large slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_large">
            <lightning-textarea class="slds-lightning-textarea" name="note" label="Note Riassegnazione" value={note}></lightning-textarea>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-combobox_container">
    <div class={comboBoxClass} tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
      <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
        <span onkeypress={handleKeyPress}>
          <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleKeyChange} onblur={handleBlur} label={inputLabel} class="searchInput"
                           is-loading={isLoading} value={searchKey} placeholder={placeholderLabel} disabled={disabledInput}></lightning-input>
        </span>
      </div>
      <template if:true={records} >
        <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-5 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
          <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
            <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
              <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" key={record.Id} onclick={onResultClick} data-record-id={record.Id}>
                <div id={record.Id} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                  <template if:true={themeInfo}>
                    <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon slds-m-top_none">
                      <div style={iconColor}>
                        <span class="uiImage" data-aura-class="uiImage">
                          <img src={themeInfo.iconUrl} class="icon " alt="Icon" title="Icon">
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </span>
                  </template>
                  <span class="slds-media__body">
                    <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">
                      <lightning-formatted-text value={record.text}></lightning-formatted-text>
                    </span>
                    <template if:true={record.meta}>
                      <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">
                        <lightning-formatted-text value={record.meta}></lightning-formatted-text>
                      </span>
                    </template>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: would need to see your code to better advise, but generally speaking, css has a z-index property which you can modify for these types of scenarios.

Comment: I tried to play with the z-index but i seems that i am not able to move the dropdown upper. If I set the z-index to -1 to the textarea of lower it disappear... (i think the textarea goes below the modal)